# remove static file logging for IIS7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, logging

Is there an easy way to prevent IIS from logging hits to static content (*.jpg, *.css, etc.), or do I have to rewrite it out manually or code a custom log provider that does this?

I already remove the logging on a per-directory basis in some cases, but it would be nice to be able to disable logging for whole classes of static files on a serverwide basis (i.e. in applicationHost.config)

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. As a security best practice, everything happening on the server should be logged. This can also help with load/traffic analysis.

You could simply ignore the static file entries in the log files, which would be much less work?

Comment: Yes good call I know. I will have to use the logparser-based rewriter I already wrote I suppose. The issue is the WebTrends analytics server on the backend-- it licenses by lines of input, so straining out static files can save a lot of hits.

Comment: I suppose we could do static file caching differently (i.e. split to separate DNS name) and just not log hits to that static content CDN-type domain, minus the security implications you mention of course...

Comment: (other than lacking logs) I like the idea of using a static.example.com host for that.